# How Do I Make Gridlines With Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm new to Stack Overflow, Python and Kivy and I tried to make gridlines for a DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) project I was working on and the code just returns 1 line. My code may look bad because I'm not really used to Python and there's no .kv file. Thanks in advance.

Here's the code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color



class MainInterface(Widget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainInterface, self).__init__()

        with self.canvas:
            linel = range(10)

            for i in linel:
                Color(1, 1, 1)
                Line(points=(i, 0, i, 1000), width=1)


class YourMusicApp(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super(YourMusicApp, self).__init__()

    def build(self):
        return MainInterface()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    YourMusicApp().run()
```

Comment: Your code works, but it is drawing vertical lines separated by 0 pixels. Just draw the vertical lines with some separation and do the same for horizontal lines.